# How can I determine if a list is a just a string or a list of strings?

Tags: erlang

I have a variable that can either contain a list of strings or a just a string. Is there a good way to tell what kind I'm dealing with?

```
"192.168.1.18" vs. ["192.168.1.18", "192.168.1.19"]
```

In either case I want to use the bits involved.

Comment: I guess the best way to do this is to avoid such situations. E.g. use a list of elements even if there is only one. Or use tuples to denote IP instead of using strings. There's always a way to avoid ambiguity

Comment: gleber: Agreed, but now I'm unfortunately dealing with legacy code where I can't introduce that kind of change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How you do it depends a lot on what you plan to do with the result, or rather how you plan to do it. So if you are interested in the bits:

```
case MyVar of
    [First|Rest] when is_list(First) -> ... First,Rest ...;
    _ -> ... MyVar ...
end
```

or if you are not interested in actually pulling apart the string/list of strings you could do:

```
if is_list(hd(MyVar)) -> ... ;
   true -> ...
end
```

Have I understood you correctly here? I have not put any code in to actually check that what should be strings actually are strings, this should have be done earlier. 
an alternative would be when generating this string/list of strings to always put it into one of the formats.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes write something like:

```
case X of
    [List|_] when is_list(List) ->
        list_of_lists;
    List when is_list(List) ->
        list;
    _ ->
        not_a_list
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Erlang implements different functions to test if a list is a flat list in module io_lib.

One good choice for checking your particulary IP strings is io_lib:latin1_char_list(Term)
http://erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#latin1_char_list-1

io_lib:latin1_char_list/1 function implementation is:

```
latin1_char_list([C|Cs]) when is_integer(C), C >= $\000, C =< $\377 ->
      latin1_char_list(Cs);
latin1_char_list([]) -> true;
latin1_char_list(_) -> false.
```

If you want to test for flat unicode lists you can use 
io_lib:char_list(Term)
http://erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#char_list-1

io_lib:char_list/1 function implementation is:

```
char_list([C|Cs]) when is_integer(C), C >= 0, C < 16#D800;
       is_integer(C), C > 16#DFFF, C < 16#FFFE;
       is_integer(C), C > 16#FFFF, C =< 16#10FFFF ->
    char_list(Cs);
char_list([]) -> true;
char_list(_) -> false.
```

Check the io_lib module documentation for other similar functions.

**Notice that** if some new erlang function are missing from your current project supported erlang version you can simply copy the implementation new erlang versions provides and add them into a module of your own. Search the latest erlang/lib/*/src source code and simply get the new functions you need.

Answer (score 0):

If this distinction needs to be determined in the function head, this is a way to figure this out in the guard:

```
1> S = "lofa".
2> T = ["hehe", "miez"].

3> is_list(S).
true
4> is_list(T).
true
```

Erlang characters are integers,

```
5> hd(S). % => 108    
6> Y = "よし". % => [12424,12375]
```

so, to **check for string inputs**:

```
7> (fun
7>     ([H|_] = L) when erlang:is_integer(H) -> yay;
7>     (_) -> nono
7>  end
7> )(S).
yay

8> (fun([H|_] = L) when erlang:is_integer(H) -> yay; (_) -> nono end)(T).
nono
```

Personally, I find the above version more intuitive than

```
9> (fun([H|_] = L) when not(erlang:is_list(H)) -> yay; (_) -> nono end)(Y).
yay
10> (fun([H|_] = L) when not(erlang:is_list(H)) -> yay; (_) -> nono end)(T).
nono
```